# iOS: Possible to export/import storyboard layouts

Tags: ios, storyboard

Is it possible to export the layout of a screen defined in a Storyboard from one app to another?  Objective here is to copy the Login screen one from app to another.

Comment: Did you mean from one 'project' to another? If so, one way how to copy the login screen is to view the storyboard file as a source code and to copy full scene that is contained between <scene> tags. Maybe you look for some more comfortable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Get ID of your view controller

[image]

**2)** Display Storyboard file as a source:

[image]

**3)** Find that ID

[image]

**4)** Copy full scene

[image]